# Preallocate multiple identically shaped numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I'm calculating a number of properties for identically sized numpy arrays (model gridded data). I'm more familiar with the matlab syntax, in which you can preallocate multiple arrays of identical sizes using a command similar to:

```
[array1,array2,array3] = deal(NaN(size(array0)));
```

At the moment my python2.7.7 (numpy1.9.0) syntax looks pretty terrible, repetitive and very much not pythonic:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.ma.zeros(np.shape(array0))
array2 = array1.copy()
array3 = array1.copy()
```

Is there a better way to do this array preallocation? I have considered using a list, but am really not certain of the best, and most pythonic way of achieving this neatly and concisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array1,array2,array3,array4 = [np.ma.zeros(np.shape(array0)) for _ in range(4)]
```

would also work ...